# Tokens or token types missing name property

Tags: email, drupal-7, token

I am having issues in tokens: Sometimes they stop working and are not available for use. When I browse the tokens only these are available.

> [image]

After I check the status report, I can see the following message.

> [image]

Tokens start working automatically, but I am not able to find out why they are not working and why they start working on their own.

I tried clearing the cache many times, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall token and entity_token using Development Tools.